# Automatically removing invalid or gramatically incorrect entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to clear out all the incorrect data from my Excel sheet, such as grammatical mistakes and invalid entries, and I want to do it automatically.

I have tried the sort and filter option, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please find the Caps Lock key on your keyboard and turn Caps Lock off. Typing in all caps is considered SHOUTING and NOT POLITE.

Comment: You might also need to explain what you mean by 'incorrect data'. You can do a find and replace, but it depends what you're changing.

Comment: Definite duplicate of [Automatically Delete Incorrectly Spelled Words from Excel Spreadsheet](http://superuser.com/q/1071984/269035)

Answer (score 3):

You can run the spell checker to help identify and correct typos. Invalid entries can be prevented by using data validation.

Sorting and filtering will not help with grammatical mistakes or invalid entries. Excel is a spreadsheet application. You can only process what you put in. If you put bad data in, you can't expect Excel to clean it up magically.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a [list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456446/dictionary-text-file) into a new worksheet (e.g. Sheet2), and, assuming your list of words to check is on the column A starting at row 3, you can add the following function on column B row 3:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(lower(A3), Sheet2!A:A, 1, false)), "***", "")
```

Then copy the formula next to all of your words, sort by column B, and delete all the occurrences of column B with `***` in it.